# Get all pages at once from an API in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks

i'm studying hooks on reactjs with an api to request data, i would like to know if theres a way to request all pages at once and show the datas at the page. The api im using its from Rick and Morty API https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/ and you can see the result here https://project-soctest.herokuapp.com/

this is what i made so far using useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
 async function loadData() {

 const apiResponse = await api.get(`?page=1`);
 setCharacters(apiResponse.data.results);
}
 loadData();
}, []);
```

Comment: It's unclear exactly what you want. Can you please elaborate on what your desired behavior is.

Comment: You need to look at the API documentation and see if it supports such a query. If so, just make that request in your hook. If not, you'll just have to loop through getting all the data

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way to get all the pages in this particular API.

Comment: can you please add some details and explain why ?

Comment: Because there is no supported keyword for getting more than 20 items in this rick and morty API  
Lets say I have this particular API which supports more item request, so the API link would be as follows
 //api/user?role=USER&limit=10&page=1
here keyword limit=10 suggests the number of items requested from the server.